# Scheduled job cannot determine target data source for lookup key null

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Customeroutingdatasource in my springboot project and defined it in my main class using @Bean annotation, then I have a service class with @EnableScheduling annotation, which make a scheduled DB call but it is giving error - "cannot determine target data source for lookup key null"

I have tried injecting the Data source in the service class.
Spring boot ver - 3.1.0
JDK 17

Comment: Well apparently you use some sort of key in a threadlocal to determine the datasource to use. This value will not be set with your scheduling (probably only with a web request) hence it fails. Without knowing your usecase (can it use a default database, does it need to do something for 1 or more customers/datasources) this is going to be impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please help me with how to set a default datasource.

Comment: That is something you need to set on the `AbstractRoutingDatasource` which has a `defaultTargetDataSource` property which, as the name indicates, does just that.

Comment: Thanks alot Man, it is solved now. New to java so facing some issues here and there daily. @M.Deinum

Comment: Well instead of directly jumping to stackoverflow I do suggest to check the documentation of the classes you are using, aka the JavaDoc. For the Spring portfolio those are pretty good next to that if you checked the properties of the class you probably could have figured it out yourself (adding to your learning experience).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.